# How can I var_dump in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

What function acts in javascript as the same behavior of var_dump() in php ?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `console.log( thing )` to print out to the JavaScript console the contents of the object `thing`.

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console). There are a few more useful ones such as:

- `console.error()`
- `console.dir()`
- `console.info()`

They are highlighted slightly differently so you should use the one that is most appropriate for the content you are printing.

Note that you can print out more than one object by separating them with a comma:

```
console.log( obj1, arr3, strFoo, numCounter );
```

Comment: I tried `console.log(my_var);` . I'm using firefox. But in the console I cannot find the logged data.

Comment: I don't use firefox so I'm not too familiar with the console there... Do you see something like this: http://i.imgur.com/9h2iFtt.png ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `console.dir(variable)` to dump its contents in your browsers developer console, depending on your browser of choice there's a few different ways to access it, but its generally by pressing F12 on your keyboard.

Note: Versions of IE older than 8 don't come with an easy to use built in developer tool, for those browsers if you still need to support them, Firebug Light might come in handy.

Comment: `dir()` can only be used for object... `log()` is a much better solution.